# VSTS unprotect git branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

Apparently the guys at VSTS decided to give the UI a new look and feel.
Negative side effect: **I cannot unprotect a previously protected branch.**

The option is greyed out. That means every commit needs to surpass a pull request approval - which I don't want anymore. Previously it was possible to switch this off quite easily.

[image: branch policy: protected branch]

**Any idea how I can turn this off?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **remove all automatic reviewers** - even though they are not enabled and you don't enforce a certain number of reviewers :-/

Once I removed all automatic reviewers I was able to untick branch protection.

Comment: Nice catch. +1 I have removed my own answer (less noise)